# React Apollo - prevent automatic invalidating cached object when child object updates

Tags: react-apollo, graphql-js

I'm implementing graphql client side implementation with React and Apollo.

## Situation

One of the queries created in server side is a wrapper object for a group of related queries, just as a namespace for grouping them:

```
query Metrics {
  metrics {
    cpu {
      cores
      avgUtilization
    }
    memory {
      size
      max
    }
    disc {
      usage
      freespace
    }
  }
}
```

so all types `cpu`, `memory` and `disk` are implemented as child/leaf types under the main type `metrics` which serves as just a namespace.

## The problem

If we have three different queries, one for running each. First we run **MetricsCPU**

```
query MetricsCPU {
  metrics {
    cpu {
      cores
      avgUtilization
    }
  }
}
```

and a while later... running **MetricsMemory**

```
query MetricsMemory {
  metrics {
    memory {
      size
      max
    }
  }
}
```

After this last query  **MetricsMemory** returns, the first query **MetricsCPU** cache invalidates and it's automatically refetched.

## Question

How can I prevent **MetricsCPU** from being invalidated and refetched after **MetricsMemory** returns?

Comment: I do not know an easy solution. One option is to remove grouping on BE which sounds a bit weird.